# C++ multidimensional array capacity

Tags: c++, arrays, capacity

I'm new to C++, and I've started to learn arrays. Here is my program on arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++){

            cout << "Enter " << j + 1 << " element of " << i + 1 << " row:";
            cin >> arr[i][j];

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            cout << j + 1 << " element of " << i + 1 << "row:";

            cout << arr[i][j] << endl;


        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I know that array's first index in C++ is zero. So, logically, an array `arr[3][3]`should have 4 * 4 = 16 elements, right? But practically, if I change 3 to 4 in my `for` cycles, I'll get out of range error. Why does it happen? Am I missing something? 
So, how much elemets are in arr[3][3]?

Comment: Oh sorry guys for such a question...It was pretty simple...  You've made that absolutely clear for me right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, logically, an array `arr[3][3]` should have `4 * 4 = 16` elements, right?

That is not correct.

For

```
int arr[3];
```

the valid element range is `arr[0]` - `arr[2]`. There are 3 elements.

For

```
int arr[3][3];
```

the valid element range is `arr[0][0]` - `arr[2][2]`. There are 9 elements.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array, you write the number of elements(not counting 0, `int arr[3]` is an array with 3 elements. Only when you use them, you start counting from 0 (`arr[2] = 666` accesses third element).

Answer (score 1):

> I know that array's first index in C++ is zero.

You are correct.

> So, logicaly, an array arr[3][3]should have 4 * 4 = 16 elements,
>   right?

Since first index is 0, arr[3][3] will be 0,1,2 rows and 0,1,2 columns. So, 9 elements
[image]

Check out this link for tutorials on array (or C++ in general ☺ )

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/